# Get URL of currently active chromium or chrome tab from external process

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, mozrepl

How can I get the current chromium tab URL from an external process in linux programmatically?

There are many similar questions to this one, but I haven't found any with the following requirements

- Solution should work from outside of the chrome process, i.e. not within javascript or a chrome extension.
- Solution should not be based on autohotkey, xdotool, wmctrl or similar tools for simulating keyboard or mouse input
- No OSX or Windows-specific solutions

In firefox, there is `mozrepl`, which exposes browser internals through an interactive repl over a TCP port. I am looking for something similar in chromium or chrome, even if it means installing a chrome extension.

Comment: Can you start chrome with a debugging port?

Comment: Yes. Although it would be helpful to also know about the security implications of such a solution.

Comment: Not much of security implications, but the problems seems to be able to identify which one is the current tab. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039569/puppeteer-chrome-get-active-visible-tab

Comment: This is not going to be easy. There's one way to do it w/o modifying Chromium source code so it will work in Chrome too. You should create an extension which will inform your another native messaging host extension about the current tab's URL. Then that native messaging host extension will write that data to a pipe or whatever IPC method you prefer so that you can use your external process to read that data

Answer (score 1):

I implemented @Asesh suggestion in https://github.com/erjoalgo/chrome-current-url, it is a chrome extension that exposes the currently active tab's URL through a local http server.

```
pip install chromeurl
sudo chromeurl --install-manifest native
```

Then install the extension from the [webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-current-url/eibefbdcoojolecpoehkpmgfaeapngjk)

Finally, query the current chrome url:

```
$ curl http://localhost:19615/tabs/current/url
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab
```