# Puppeteer chrome get active/visible tab

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

In a chrome extension you can use below to find the active tab in a window

```
chrome.tabs.query({
            currentWindow: true,
            active: true,
        }
```

I have a below code which connects to existing browser and get all the pages. I am not able to make out if there is a way for me to know which tab/page is currently the active one and get its url (`page.url()`, but which one from the the array to use?)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

debuggerUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:9999/json/version"

const request = require('request');

request(debuggerUrl, function (error, response, body) {
  data = JSON.parse(body);
  webSocketDebuggerUrl = data["webSocketDebuggerUrl"];
  console.log("Connecting to ", webSocketDebuggerUrl);
  puppeteer.connect({browserWSEndpoint: webSocketDebuggerUrl}).then(async browser => {
    var pages = await browser.pages();
    console.log(pages);
    console.log(await browser.targets())
    await browser.disconnect();
  })
});
```

Comment: Am trying to achieve the same thing. You did it?

Comment: Nope, was not able to get anything on this

Answer (score 1):

`document.hidden` is now deprecated. But we can use [document.visibilityState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilityState)

note that `page` will always refer to the same tab even if you have change to different tab. So you have to change `page` to the active tab manually.

```js
const pages = await browser.pages();
// this will return list of active tab (which is pages object in puppeteer)
const visiblePages = pages.filter(async (p) => {
  const state = await p.evaluate(() => document.visibilityState);
  return state === 'visible';
});
const activeTab = visiblePages[0]; // since there should be only 1 active tab per window
```

Comment: This will not work as you pass async function to the filter. You have to use async filter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355528/filtering-an-array-with-a-function-that-returns-a-promise

Answer (score 1):

```
    const pages = await browser.pages();
    const vis_results = await Promise.all(pages.map(async (p) => {
        const state = await p.evaluate(() => document.webkitHidden);
        return !state;
    }));
    let visiblePage = pages.filter((_v, index) => vis_results[index])[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [document.hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hidden)

```js
const pages = await browser.pages()
let page
for (let i = 0; i < pages.length && !page; i++) {
    const isHidden = await pages[i].evaluate(() => document.hidden)
    if (!isHidden) {
        page = pages[i]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get all pages and check `visibilityState`. It is easy to do with async filter helper function:

```js
// helper for async filter
async function filter(arr, callback) {
    const fail = Symbol()
    return (await Promise.all(arr.map(async item => (await callback(item)) ? item : fail))).filter(i=>i!==fail)
}

// filtering only visible pages, it should be one
const visiblePages = await filter(await browser.pages(), async (p) => {
    const state = await p.evaluate(() => document.visibilityState);
    return state === 'visible';
});
// getting it
const activeTab = visiblePages[0];
```